# Animate a complete human with only JS + HTML (K3D)

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

i need to animate a complete human body in the browser. This means there needs to be a 3d Version of a human body, which is rotateable by using the mouse and where the user can click on it, to light some specific parts.

I searched a lot via Google now and found Canvas K3D (https://launchpad.net/canvask3d) and jsc3d. Both seem to be what i need but since i could only find a very short summary about how the library works for K3D i want to use this one. Short summary / tutorial on how it works:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/K3D_JavaScript_Canvas_Library

Now there are several propblems:

1. There is by far not everything described in this tutorial. For example: How can i rotate the recently rendered objects (eg: a simple square)?
2. What would be the best option to divide the body into 6 areas which are selectable / unselectable each? Simply using 6 different objects?
3. How can i "draw" something complex like a human body? I mean its not possible to do this by just summing up thousands of coordinates like in the tutorial for a simple square.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess you are looking something similar to http://www.zygotebody.com/ which use WebGL API alongside HTML5

Comment: @ AurA: That looks quite good! The problem is, that it needs to be just JS + HTML, nothing special else. I need it to run in every Browser, and i need 6 different parts of the body to be selectable / unselectable of course.

Comment: that site you looked will only work in Firefox and Chrome which uses WebGL extensively, IE does not support WebGL. Try opening that site in IE it will give you error.. that WebGL is required. Actually without WebGL you cannot basically render such good graphics, but downside is it will not work in IE.

Comment: zygotebody is based on Open 3D viewer, for which source code is available at https://code.google.com/p/open-3d-viewer/

Comment: Hm, so according to wikipedia and your information WebGL only runs in Safari, Opera, Chrome and Firefox. Not in IE. The problem is that i need it to run EVERYWHERE. Which means i cannot use something like WebGL which is not running everywhere. Means: Only JS + HTML. (The good thing is that the 3d body doesn't need to be any detailed. Just some 3d model that everybody recognizes as a human body). Any other ideas than WebGL?

Comment: If you are ok with css3 means try this link: http://andrew-hoyer.com/experiments/walking/#